# strange failure with const pointer and templates

Tags: c++, templates

The following code doesn't compile I am out of ideas as to why:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

template <typename MapT>
inline typename MapT::mapped_type * find_element(MapT &m, const typename MapT::key_type &key)
{
  auto it = m.find(key);
  return it != m.end() ? &it->second : NULL;
}

int main() {
  std::map<std::string, double> map0;
  const std::map<std::string, double> map1 = map0;
  auto d1 = find_element(map1, "test");
  std::cout << d1 << "\n";
}
```

I get:

```
const.cc: In instantiation of ‘typename MapT::mapped_type* find_element(MapT&, const typename MapT::key_type&) [with MapT = const std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, double>; typename MapT::mapped_type = double; typename MapT::key_type = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
const.cc:15:38:   required from here
const.cc:9:24: error: invalid conversion from ‘const double*’ to ‘std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, double>::mapped_type*’ {aka ‘double*’} [-fpermissive]
    9 |   return it != m.end() ? &it->second : NULL;
      |                        ^
      |                        |
      |                        const double*
```

Comment: Because you're passing a `const` map, then `it` is a `const_iterator`, `it->second` return `const double`, `&it->second` returns `const double*` which doesn't match the return type `double *`.

Comment: Just add `const` in the return type. Seee [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oKW1nKb4K)

Comment: i think my mistake here was that i assumed that "const" is part of the type and will get specialized as a different method from the non-const one.  But that's not how C++ templating works i guess.

Comment: Side note: Don't use `NULL` in modern C++ - use `nullptr`.

Comment: This sort of thing is why they gave up on all the typedefs like `mapped_type` and add `decltype` to the language. Instead of guessing what `*` returns you can use `decltype(&m.front().second)`. A bonus is that then maybe `m` doesn't even need to be a map.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `MapT` is deduced as `const std::map<std::string, double>` since you're passing a const map. This in turn means that `it` is deduced as(from the initializer) as a `std::map<const std::string, double>::const_iterator`. Thus, the type of `it->second` will be `const double` and `&it->second` is `const double*`.

And since the return type is `double*` and as we're not allowed to initialize a `double*` from a `const double*`, you get the mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're returning a const from a function that is not a const, this should work

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

template <typename MapT>
const inline typename MapT::mapped_type* find_element(MapT& m, const typename MapT::key_type& key)
{
    auto it = m.find(key);
    return it != m.end() ? &it->second : NULL;
}

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, double> map0;
    const std::map<std::string, double> map1 = map0;
    auto d1 = find_element(map1, "test");
    std::cout << d1 << "\n";
}
```

passing a const caused the compiler to pick everything up as a const, &it->second returns as a const double*, and you can't initialize a double* with a const double*